# how do I implicitly convert enumtypes in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am getting below error.

> Error  BC30512 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'clsDataTypes.enmMiscTransTypes' to 'clsDataTypes.enmMiscTransDistributions'".

Below mentioned is the code and I am passing an optional parameter to a sub like below.

```
Public Sub NotifyDisbursementDistribChanged(
    Optional ByVal enmRemovedDistribOption As clsDataTypes.enmMiscTransDistributions = clsDataTypes.enmMiscTransTypes.ValueNotSet)

End Sub
```

These two are the enumtypes.

```
Public Enum enmMiscTransDistributions
    ValueNotSet = -1
    Check = 0
    Wire = 1
    PlanWire = 3
    Test2= 9
End Enum

Public Enum enmMiscTransTypes
    ValueNotSet = -1
    MiscReceipt = 1         
    test2= 9        
    test5= 11

End Enum
```

Comment: Try using [CType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/ctype-function)

Comment: Or [DirectCast()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/directcast-operator):  `DirectCast(enmMiscTransTypes.ValueNotSet, enmMiscTransDistributions)`

Comment: Ctype will not work as you can see I am assigning a value(.ValueNotSet=-1)

Comment: `CType` will work exactly as desired as long as the values correspond; in this case, they do as `ValueNotSet` is -1 in both enums.  However, given that `ValueNotSet` is the *only* equivalent value in the two enums, perhaps you shouldn't be trying to convert, and instead should change to use the correct enum (or possibly some common one that only has `ValueNotSet`).  It's not clear why you're trying to use the other enum.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/nullable-value-types

Comment: @HansPassant I don't see how the link is relevant to this question

Comment: It is a good way to avoid ValueNotSet hacks, what got the OP in trouble by thinking the enum type did not matter for the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So why use the other enum type?

```
Public Sub NotifyDisbursementDistribChanged(
    Optional ByVal enmRemovedDistribOption As clsDataTypes.enmMiscTransDistributions = clsDataTypes.enmMiscTransDistributions.ValueNotSet)

End Sub
```

I mean, what is the point of using the wrong enum? They both have ValueNotSet = -1. So just use the correct one...?

Comment: Thanks.. I am going to use as you mentioned.

Comment: @vandy great. I'm just curious, why did you try to set the default value from the wrong enum in the first place?